# How to calculate predictions with both standard errors and random effects for ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm trying to prepare my data for a ggplot. The mating variable is binomial. So fit3 is the model I would like to plot.(assumptions have been tested and are okay)

Then I made a summary which sums all the values for a treatment and batch number and adds a column with the total sum. So far so good. I also give those columns a clear name.

```
    treatment batch     mating          total
1     control exp_0          9            24
2     control exp_1         13            23
3     control exp_2         16            24
4 9-tricosene exp_0          1            24
5 C23 blend 1 exp_2         16            24
6 C23 blend 2 exp_1         12            24
7 C23 blend 3 exp_2          8            24
```

But then I try to make a prediction value using my model so I can use this to create error bars on the plot. but I get the error :

> "Error in predict.merMod(fit3, newdata = data_widematingfig5, interval
>   = "confidence",  :    cannot calculate predictions with both standard errors and random effects"

So I can't receive the predictions because of that random effect (batch number) But I really need that since the controls differ quite a lot between batches.
So I would like to receive the predictions for each treatment and batch number.

```
fit3 = glmer(mating ~ treatment + (1|batch), 
             family = binomial(link = logit), 
             data = datafig5) #correction for batch.

data_widematingfig5 = summaryBy(mating ~ treatment|batch, 
                                data = datafig5, 
                                FUN = c(sum, length))
data_widematingfig5

colnames(data_widematingfig5) = c("treatment","batch", "mate","total")
data_widematingfig5

predictmatfig5 = predict(fit3, 
                         newdata = data_widematingfig5,                 
                         interval = 'confidence',
                         type="response") * 100
predictmatfig5

p = predict(fit3, 
            newdata = data_widematingfig5, 
            interval='confidence',
            type="response", 
            se.fit = TRUE)

predictmatfig4 = p$fit * 100
predictmatfig4le = p$se.fit * 100
predictmatfig4
```

Comment: this doesn't actually answer your question, but I will note that you can recieve standard error estimates of predicted values IF you tell the `predict.merMod` function NOT to include random effects via the `re.form = NA` argument.